# How to Optimize Predictive Classification Model for Lead Time

Tags: regression, logistic, classification

How do I optimize a predictive classification model to reward variables and values that give predictions earlier in sequential data?

For example:

Let's say I'm modelling whether an upcoming relationship will be successful as a factor of the number of days we've been in the relationship + other factors. I'd prefer to know earlier than later whether we're going to break up.  As a result, in my model, I'd prefer to give more weight to variables that help predict a breakup in less days in relationship, even if it means sacrificing accuracy.

Is there an approach I can take that doesn't just optimize for the DidItLast classifier, but also minimizes the days to classification?

[image]

Comment: To accomplish this, you will need to be able to compute variables like `did_it_last_up_to_five_days`, etc.  Then you really just want to fit models to predict these variables.